# Flutter how to implement feature on desktop that simulate typing at any window input?

Tags: flutter

I saw there was an APP using electron.js achieved:

typing text from program (don't know what principle), in any window for any desktop application.

link: https://helper.im/

Just wonder:

1. Totally missed out how to acheive this in flutter;
2. any workable demo can try out?

This feature is really useful, but got NO way to figure out, at least electron.js can do this. I think flutter would possible maybe too.